# Sending multiple files to google bucket with multer - why are my files empty?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-storage, multer

I previously had a single file upload set up and working properly. Now I need to make it handle multiple files.

Here is my code right now:

```
const multer = require('multer')
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage')

const storage = new Storage()

const m = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage()  })

module.exports = app => {
  app.use('/', router)
  router.post(
    '/reader-:shortId/file-upload',
    passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
    m.array('files'),
    async function (req, res) {
      const bucketName = req.params.shortId.toLowerCase()
      await storage.createBucket(bucketName)
      bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName)
      let promises = []

      req.files.forEach((file) => {
        const blob = bucket.file(file.originalname)
        const newPromise =  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          blob.createWriteStream({
            metadata: { contentType: file.mimetype }
          }).on('finish', async response => {
            await blob.makePublic()
            resolve(response)
          }).on('error', err => {
            reject('upload error: ', err)
          }).end()
        })
       promises.push(newPromise)
     })

     Promise.all(promises).then((response) => {
       // the response I get here is [undefined, undefined]
       res.status(200).send(response)
     }).catch((err) => {
       res.status(400).send(err.message)
     });
    })
  }
```

req.files does give me an array of files, with a buffer and a size that makes sense.
The promises all resolve.
But once I check the files in the google bucket, they have the right name but don't have any content (and size of 0)

As I said before, it was working when I was doing it with one file (using m.single('file')

I don't want to use the bucket as the destination with multer setup because I also have to change the file name before uploading to google bucket.

edit: this is the code example given by google cloud documentations for single file uploads (https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-storage):

```
function sendUploadToGCS (req, res, next) {
  if (!req.file) {
    return next();
  }

  const gcsname = Date.now() + req.file.originalname;
  const file = bucket.file(gcsname);

  const stream = file.createWriteStream({
    metadata: {
      contentType: req.file.mimetype
    },
    resumable: false
  });

  stream.on('error', (err) => {
    req.file.cloudStorageError = err;
    next(err);
  });

  stream.on('finish', () => {
    req.file.cloudStorageObject = gcsname;
    file.makePublic().then(() => {
      req.file.cloudStoragePublicUrl = getPublicUrl(gcsname);
      next();
    });
  });

  stream.end(req.file.buffer);
}
```

I originally had something like that working, but I just don't understand where it is getting the file buffer data from. That is probably where things are different with multiple files.

Comment: I don't see where you're actually writing the contents of `file`.  The only properties of `file` I see in use are `originalname` and `mimetype`.

Answer (score 2):

I know its too late, but someone might looking an answer for **uploading multiple files** on Google Cloud Storage.

Dependencies:

- Express
- Google Cloud Library
- Multer
- Body Parser

This is the controller code.

```
exports.post_image_upload = async (req, res) => {
   /** Check if file exist */
   if (!req.files) {
       res.status(400).send('No file uploaded.');
       return;
   }

   let PublicUrls = []

   req.files.forEach((file) => {
       const blob = bucket.file(file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))

       const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream({
           metadata: { contentType: file.mimetype }
       })
       blobStream.on('finish', ()=> {
           blob.makePublic()           
       })
       blobStream.on('error', err => {
           //Put your error message here
       })
       blobStream.end(file.buffer)

       const Url = `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${blob.name}`

       PublicUrls.push(Url)
   })

   res.send(PublicUrls)
}
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

Ok, turns out I had to change
`.end()`
to 
`.end(file.buffer)`

Answer (score 0):

Marie Pelletier, I think your approach is 100% right. I modified a little your code trying to avoid the async response:

```
let promises = []
req.files.forEach((file) => {
  const blob = bucket.file(file.originalname)
  const newPromise =  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    blob.createWriteStream({
      metadata: { contentType: file.mimetype },
      resumable: false //Good for small files
    }).on('finish', () => {
      const Url = `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${blob.name}`;
      resolve({ name: file.originalname, url: Url });
    }).on('error', err => {
      reject('upload error: ', err);
    }).end(file.buffer);
  })
  promises.push(newPromise);
})

Promise.all(promises).then((response) => {
  res.status(200).send(response)
}).catch((err) => {
  res.status(400).send(err.message)
});
```

This way, I didn't get 'undefined' anymore.